# Terragrunt import with no root main.tf?

Tags: import, terraform, terragrunt

I want to run *terragrunt import* on an external module.  (This resource exists in the real world and I want to pull it into my state).

```
# terragrunt.hcl
terraform {
  source = "../../../../..//modules/environment"
}

inputs = {
  env_list = [
    {
        name = "dev"
    }
  ]
}


# modules/environments/main.tf
resource "confluentcloud_environment" "environment" {
  provider = confluentcloudofficial
  count = length(var.env_list)
  display_name = var.env_list[count.index].name
}
```

> terragrunt import 'confluentcloud_environment.enviroment[0]' env-299n2

is the command I'd use I think (I get this resource name from a terragrunt plan) but I'm left with this error:

> Error: resource address "confluentcloud_environment.enviroment[0]"
> does not exist in the configuration.
>
> Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the
> root module. For example:
>
> resource "confluentcloud_environment" "enviroment" {   # (resource
> arguments) }

Is it possible to import existing state into Terraform (via Terragrunt) without first declaring it in a root main.tf?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was delete the contents in the .terragrunt-cache folder and try again.  3 days of my life...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while moving stuff from Terraform to Terragrunt.
I used `terraform state list` + `terraform state show <someresource` in the older project to later run `terragrunt import`.

There was stuff shown in `terraform state list` that weren't in sync with newer code. Long story short, **I really didn't have the resource declared in newer Terragrunt module code. Double check that.**

EXTRA: Also don't forget `--terragrunt-source` attribute when pointing to modules on your local machine.